# Duplicate email address in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

Gmail treats any email with dot (.) in it as the same as without dots. For example mail sent to hello@gmail.com or he.ll.o@gmail.com or he.llo@gmail.com will be sent to the same address. How will you store this in the database so that you avoid duplicate usage of emails with dots in it. For example if a user registers first with salman.khan@gmail.com , he should not be able to use any variation of the same email like sal.mankhan@gmail.com or salman.khan@gmail.com . (Assume the database have 10M of users).

Answer (score 1):

You could remove .'s prior to saving them on the server, eg...

```js
let emailone = "hello@gmail.com"
let emailtwo = "hel.lo@gmail.com"

const normaliseEmails = email => email.split('@')[0].replaceAll(".", "") + "@" + email.split('@')[1]

console.log(normaliseEmails(emailone))
console.log(normaliseEmails(emailtwo))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good you're thinking about this, as it can bite you later. Unless you are never going to use or reflect back the email address of a user,  you'll likely want to keep the dots so you can show them. So what to do?

If this is important problem to solve, I'd add a second column to your database, a `canonical email`. This would be the email addresses without the dots. Then, when looking up email addresses, "canonize" the input by removing the periods, and then look it up using this column.

Your database may be able to do this dynamically for you, depending on its features. Be cognizant that this might not be performant as the database grows, but may be okay short term.

You may also want consider other "features" of email addresses, such as the ability to add optional stuff before the `@`, as in `joe+duplicate@example.com`, which gets routed to `joe@example.com`. This is likely fine, but you may want to guard against it as well.